# Ckeditor: customize specific areas

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to enable Ckeditor on a specific website page to manage HTML content.

The problem is that I would like to keep a specific HTML strcture as following:

```
<div>
<div id="div1" class="full">
    <div id="div1_content" class="content">
        Some text
        <a class="link1" href="#">Some link caption</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="presentation" class="content">
    <h3>Some title</h3>
    <div class="description">
        Some description text (lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer ...)
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to make each "text" elements customisable:

- Some text
- Some link caption
- Some title
- Some description text (lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer ...)

The aim is to prevent changes into HTML strcture (I guess there should be some "readonly" parts).

If not implemented with ckeditor, maybe I can use another plugin?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

How about making each text section an inline editor? This way the surrounding HTML isn't even loaded into the editor and thus is safe. The wrapping/unwrapping could be done on the fly too if the wrappers are an issue. You could do this with the single row elements such as H3 by customizing a very strict ACF rule (or using an alternative method, such as converting it to a text input manually).

As for the link, I would use an alternative editing solution or if it's necessary to use CKE for that too (why?), the strict ACF approach.

```
<div id="div1" class="full">
    <div id="div1_content" class="content">
        <div class="inlineEditor">
            Some text
        </div>
        <a class="link1" href="#">Some link caption</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="presentation" class="content">
    <h3>Some title</h3>
    <div class="description">
        <div class="inlineEditor">
            Some description text (lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer ...)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CKEditor widgets](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets) could be something you are looking for.

> Widgets are special rich content units in that they are groups of elements which are treated as a single entity inside the editor.
>
> Once developed, their structure (but not necessarily their content) is immutable and enforced by the CKEditor instance they are used in. These entities can thus be selected and deleted or moved freely as a whole around the editing area, keeping their predefined structure intact. At the same time all the individual parts of the widget (its "building blocks") can be edited or configured separately, again, without affecting the whole widget entity and its structure in the process.

See in particular the [basic template widget called "Simple Box"](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/simplebox.html) that was created for demonstration purposes in a [step-by-step tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1), with source code readily available. You should be able to adjust it to your needs, creating your custom structure, without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

For information, I finally used http://createjs.org/